# Initialization files on Windows 7 and Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, filesystems, window

Why do win.ini and system.ini files still exists in C:\Windows directory in Windows 7 and Windows 10? The research I found stated that win.ini and system.ini files don't exist in Windows 7 and Windows 10 because the functions of these two files is handled by the registry.  I checked my Windows 10 box and found both these files still there.

Answer (score 2):

These files are still there because they are used to make the system backward compatible to old legacy programs which were last used on Windows 3.11.You can also open the "win.ini" file to see the following comment which indicates that the file is used for backward compatibility:
`; for 16-bit app support`